# What is the coating of this spring roll called, and how is it made?

Tags: asian-cuisine, food-identification, vietnamese-cuisine, rolls

I had these spring rolls at a restraunt, but as you can see the outside was quite different to the 'normal' spring rolls I usually see.

The texture is light and crispy and looks 'stringy (but doesn't taste or feel that way).

I think it was quite interesting and would like to give them a shot but aren't sure what they're called to search for a recipe.

[image: Spring Rolls]

Comment: @Spagirl even if you are not sure that your answer is correct, please don't add it as a comment, since that breaks the quality mechanisms of the site. You can either bite the bullet and write an answer, or leave it out altogether.

Answer (score 6):

It's regular roll made with *net rice wrapper*
It's common wrapper in Vietnam. 
Here's site when you can see the package and rolls made with it [bearnakedfood](http://www.bearnakedfood.com/2016/06/17/net-spring-rolls/)

Answer (score 3):

The dish you ate is called *Chả giò rế*.
The coating is called *Bánh tráng rế*.

"Rế" is hisitorically a rattan or bamboo net to rest hot pans and pots after cooking.

*Bánh tráng rế* is made mainly from rice powder. But there are also variations which are made from a mixture of rice powder, corn powder and cassava powder. Some salt and sugar are added too.

Making *Bánh tráng rế* is a crossover of making rice papers and noodles. Traditionally, you have a fryer with a flat and wide surface. Soggy rice liquid will be poured into that hot surface to get steamed through tiny holes drilled from a container.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nv70xZ5sJHw

Answer (score 1):

In London from a Vietnamese restaurant, I have received this variant of the spring roll.

It is called Chả Giò Rế Chiên Giòn (the "nest" variant of Chả Giò spring roll)

Beautiful Google images here :) 
https://www.google.com/search?q=Ch%E1%BA%A3+Gi%C3%B2+R%E1%BA%BF+Chi%C3%AAn+Gi%C3%B2n&tbm=isch